# Why is the hierarchy of Kashyapa different?

Tags: ramayana, kashyapa

As I was listening to a talk, I found out that Jatayu and Sampati are grand children to Kashyapa. After doing some research over Kashyapa, I found out that one of the wives to Kashyapa, Kudru has given birth to Nagas.

What's confusing me is that how can a human species give birth to a different species?

Comment: Kashyapa married many wives and most of the species came from them.. he is one of the prajapatis (divine being) and not just human..